# Find a coordinate inside Circle using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to find out a coordinate inside a Circle drawn on Google Map.

How to find a coordinate is inside Circle drawn on Google Map using Laravel ?

Answer (score 1):

when you have spatially stored coordinates, you can use this to find out whether a coordinate is inside the circle or not

```
$selected_point = new Point($latitude, $longitude);
$circle = CircleStoreModel::whereRaw(
        "ST_Distance(coordinates, ?) <= radius",
        [$targetPoint]
    )->first();

    if ($circle) {
        return 'Coordinate is inside a circle';
    }

    return 'Coordinate is outside all circles';
```

And if coordinates are separated in lat and lng then may you use this

```
public function checkCoordinateInCircle($latitude, $longitude)
{
    $selected_point = ['lat' => $latitude, 'lng' => $longitude];
    
    $circles = CircleStoreModel::all();
    
    foreach ($circles as $circle) {
        $circleCenter = $circle->coordinates;
        $circleRadius = $circle->radius;
        
        $distance = $this->calculateDistance($circleCenter,$selected_point);
        
        if ($distance <= $circleRadius) {
            return 'Coordinate is inside a circle';
        }
    }
    
    return 'Coordinate is outside all circles';
}

private function calculateDistance($point1, $point2)
{
    $lat1 = deg2rad($point1->getLat());
    $lon1 = deg2rad($point1->getLng());
    $lat2 = deg2rad($point2['lat']);
    $lon2 = deg2rad($point2['lng']);

    // Haversine formula to calculate the distance between two coordinates
    $dlat = $lat2 - $lat1;
    $dlon = $lon2 - $lon1;
    $a = sin($dlat / 2) * sin($dlat / 2) + cos($lat1) * cos($lat2) * sin($dlon / 2) * sin($dlon / 2);
    $c = 2 * atan2(sqrt($a), sqrt(1 - $a));
    $distance = 6371000 * $c; // Radius of Earth in meters

    return $distance;
}
```